# How to convert an Arraylist of Characters to an array of chars

Tags: java

I am working on a project when I create ArrayList of characters(`ArrayList<Character>`) to dynamically add elements to the list.

How do I, then, convert this into an array of `char`? (This is needed as part of the later functions.)

Comment: do you need `Character[]` or `char[]`?

Comment: It is a mutable array list, not a static array

Comment: char[] is what i needed

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer...? Or give some feedback on them?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `List<Character>` vs. a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Oh, well. It was read as List<Character> because it was needed to process each character and find if there is a reoccurring sequence. But since the length are unknown, therefore List of Characters are used. But I think maybe I can just use the list to apply the algo with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend just iterating through the entire arraylist and adding the chars to your array.

```
char[] myCharArray = new char[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    myCharArray[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: When I use this method, my list contains ['a','b','c'], but the outcome somehow became [C@fee4648? Any reason why?

Comment: @oasisweng I am not sure about that, I would have to see your code. Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Nope, thank you. But I ended up reading in a string and toCharArray. It is easier that way

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a quick method that would do that for you:

```
public static char[] convert(final List<Character> list){
    final char[] array = new char[list.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: The Joshes killed it on that one :P

Comment: Or, you know, just call `List.toArray()`

Comment: @BrianRoach Sure, if he wanted a `Character[]` (which he doesn't, as he stated in an earlier comment). @oasisweng Doesn't matter, as long as it is a subclass of `List`

Comment: You must have a time machine since that "earlier" comment was a reply to me asking after I commented on your answer.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma gave me an answer early. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public char[] toArray(List<Character> list){
    char[] toReturn = new char[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(char c : list)
        toReturn[i ++] = c;
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily iterate through the array like the other answers have specified, but this is a different way to do it:

```
Character[] array = new Character[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);
```

The only problem with this is it doesn't work for the primitive type `char` so you have to use the wrapper class `Character`

It doesn't change anything, except that you're using a `Character` class array vs. a `char` array.

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    list.add('a');
    list.add('x');
    list.add('j');

    Character[] array = new Character[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[a, x, j]
```

Take a look at the [<kbd>Docs</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray) for information on ArrayList methods.

Comment: I am sure I said chars not Characters

Comment: characters and Characters? Actually, no. characters(chars) are primitive datatype inherited from C, but Characters are objects. You will be unable to use .toArray on primitive data type. If you don't believe, you can try it out.