# ArrayList<String> always produces a char[], not a string. how can i fix it?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to write a method that takes a string as an argument and produces an arraylist of strings, which are the words contained in the string given. E.g. the string "I go to Mars" should be turned into the Arraylist ["I","go","to","Mars"]. Here is the code:

```java
    static ArrayList<String> getWords(String str){
        ArrayList<Character> charArr = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<String> strArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
        for (Character i : chArr) {
            if (((int) i) != 32) {
                charArr.add(i);
            }
            else {
                strArr.add(charArr.toString());
                charArr.clear();
            }
        }
        if (! charArr.isEmpty()) strArr.add(charArr.toString());
        return strArr;
    }
```

The issue is that, instead of getting the desired Array of Strings, I get an Array of charArrays. 
Expected output:

> ["I","go","to","Mars"].

Actual output:

> [[I],[g,o],[t,o],[M,a,r,s]].

I am also not able to convert these char Arrays into strings, which I tried to do via

```java
String string = new String(getWords(str).get(1));
```

How can I fix this? Preferably in the getWords-method.

Comment: That code clearly creates an `ArrayList` of `String`s, not an `ArrayList` of `char[]`. ([Proof](http://ideone.com/OcWNNt)) What makes you think it does the latter? The code doesn't do what you've said you want it to do, but it doesn't produce the wrong data type.

Comment: To answer your question, go read the javadoc of List.toString(). It won't concatenate all the chars that it contains to return a String.

Comment: The strings it's producing are the string versions of the `ArrayList<Character>`, because you're using its `toString`. That doesn't turn the characters into a string, it returns a string representation **of the list**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with the `String.split()` method:

```
public static List<String> getWords(String str){
    String[] strArray=str.split(" "); 
    List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String strInArray : strArray){
          listStr.add(strInArray);
    }

    return listStr;
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/) to geeksforgeeks website which explain more about the `split` method with examples.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by changing your method as below,

```
static List<String> getWords(String str){
    String[] splitValue = str.split(" ");
    return Arrays.asList(splitValue);
}
```

If you call the aboce method with `getWords("I go to mars")`, It will return a List of String as `[I, go, to, mars]`

If you want the method to specifically return and ArrayList of String it can be achieved by,

```
static ArrayList<String> getWords(String str){
    String[] splitValue = str.split(" ");
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitValue));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The strings your code is producing are the string versions of the `ArrayList<Character>`, because you're using its [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()). That doesn't turn the characters into a string, it returns a string representation **of the list**.

Of course, you could just [use `split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57745013/157247), but I assume this is some kind of exercise...

If you want to turn the `ArrayList<Character>` into a `String`, it's [a bit awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346830/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-of-characters-to-an-array-of-chars) because the list contains `Character` objects, not `char`s. You'd probably be better off just using `chArr` and an index, no need for the `ArrayList<Character>` at all:

```
static ArrayList<String> getWords(String str){
    ArrayList<String> strArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= chArr.length; ++i) {
    //                ^^---- Note the unusual end condition
        if (i == chArr.length || chArr[i] == ' ') {
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- note the test to avoid doing `chArr[i]` when past the end
            strArr.add(new String(chArr, lastIndex, i - lastIndex));
            lastIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return strArr;
}
```

Or use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of the `ArrayList<Character>`, or...